# Interpreting a quote from Don Quixote

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Can someone breakdown the meaning of:

> The reason for the unreason to which my reason is subjected, so
>   weakens my reason that I have reason to complain of your beauty.

From Don Quixote Ch.1

Comment: It is intended to be confusing.

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of this site. Part of the problem stems from the translation of  _razón _ and _sinrazón_, and the ways they can be played on in Spanish.  _razón_ means reason, yes, but _con razón_ means "justly", or rightly.  _sinrazón_ is not really "inability to think reasonably", but rather _accion injusta cometida con abuso de poder_ according to my Larousse. And in DRAE it is  _Acción hecha contra justicia y fuera de lo razonable o debido_ . In other words "an unjust act" or abuse of power. The translator is trying to retain the sense of the original as much as possible,

Comment: sinrazon es locura, madness. He became loved crazed for Dulcinea.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, it is one of [many meanings](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/sinraz%C3%B3n): _injusticia, error, arbitrariedad, atropello, contrasentido, ilegalidad, abuso, parcialidad, despotismo, locura_ , which is what makes it so useful in this context. Atropello is interesting...basically "run over".

Comment: Actually, the Dulcinea thing is an over-reading by me. Nevertheless, madness is not. It's really the whole point of the sentence. It's not nothing that makes me be without my reason.  The DRAE definition is modern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fun wordplay. Switch some of the words and you'll see the meaning:

The **cause** for the **confusion** to which my **mind** is subjected, so weakens my **mind** that I have **cause** to complain of your beauty.

OR

My mind is scrambled because of your beauty.

Comment: Nice interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

What Cervantes actually wrote in the Quijote was this:

> *La **razón** de la **sinrazón** que a mi **razón** se hace, de tal
>   manera mi **razón** enflaquece, que con **razón** me quejo de la vuestra fermosura.
>   Y también cuando leía: los altos cielos que de vuestra **divinidad
>   divinamente** con las estrellas se fortifican, y os hacen **merecedora** del
>   **merecimiento** que **merece** la vuestra grandeza.*

You can see from the words I’ve set in bold that he was deliberately repeating words derived from the same stems.

In a comment, Cascabel wrote:

> This is probably beyond the scope of this site. Part of the problem stems from the translation of  *razón* and *sinrazón*, and the ways they can be played on in Spanish:
>
> - *razón* means reason, yes, but *con razón* means "justly", or rightly.
> - *sinrazón* is not really "inability to think reasonably", but rather *acción injusta cometida con abuso de poder* according to my Larousse. And in DRAE it is  *Acción hecha contra justicia y fuera de lo razonable o debido*. In other words "an unjust act" or abuse of power.
>
> The translator is trying to retain the sense of the original as much as possible.

Where the long bits in Spanish from the cited dictionary entries given for *sinrazón*, which was translated into “unreason” in English, are:

- An *“acción injusta cometida con abuso de poder”*  can be translated as “an unjust action committed through the abuse of power”.
- An *“acción hecha contra justicia y fuera de lo razonable o debido”* can be translated as “an action carried out (=made, done, taken) against justice beyond what is reasonable or required”.

Comment: @Cascabel ¡No quise dejarla como comentario por si las moscas!

Comment: ¡ _No tenga pena_ !  BTW Part of the issue is that the way _sinrazón_ is used nowadays, and the way I think it was used then, has probably changed. The modern usage is more likely closer to the English translation cited, but I think Cervantes was thinking of it in the "abuse" meaning.

Comment: Perder la razón means to become mad, if you become mad you are sinrazón. He, basically, is saying he has lost his senses.

Comment: @Lambie But he did not say _Perder la razón_. Please see my other comment to you above.

Comment: Just for hahas I linked the DRAE with [the many usages of razón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFaWIYq). As you can see, different verbs change the meaning significantly.

Comment: Yes, D. Quixote was as mad as a hatter. Further down in the text it even says: Con estas razones ***perdía el pobre caballero el juicio***, And again: y así, del poco dormir y del mucho leer, se le secó el celebro de manera que vino a perder el juicio (And thus, from so little sleeping and so much reading, his brain dried up so he came to lose his judgment). My analysis of sinrazón is not from the dictionary; it's based on perder la razón y pues estar sin razón (loco).

Comment: It's true he didn't say literally perder la razón but one can hardly read the word sinrazón and Don Quixote without realizing this is indeed about being mad.

Comment: @Lambie y Cascabel ¿Pues cómo os parece que con tanta charla esta pregunta sea migrada a [spanish.se]? :)

Answer (score 1):

> La razón de la sinrazón que a mi razón se hace, de tal manera mi razón enflaquece, que con razón me quejo de la vuestra fermosura.

That is the quote in Don Quixote where the author is discussing the many works of romance the hereo (Don Quixot) has been filling his head with before going off on his quest. And he quotes an author called Francisco Silva whom he admires. Notes to the version at the [Virtual Cervantes Institute](http://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/clasicos/quijote/edicion/parte1/cap01/default.htm) says that the quotation was not literal.

> The reason for the madness which assails my reason does weaken it, [and] I have not lost my reason in complaining of your beauty.

One has to take certain liberties with the sentence's structure, as it is purposefully (probably) somewhat odd.

The puns revolve around the word *razón* which translates to "reason", but in the philosophical sense and mental sense. *Sinrazón* in this case, literally, "without reason" is a way of saying madness. In Latin languages, to lose one's reason is to go mad. *Perder la razón*.

Indeed, D. Quixote is quite mad. The passage also says he loved these old books from an earlier age and stayed up all night reading them. He did this so much that he "lost his brain". He actually sold parcels of his land in order to buy these old books.

Whose beauty this is, is not clear. Later on in the book, we learn of his love for Dulcinea, an imaginary woman of great beauty for whom he goes to battle like the knights of old who would do battle in the name of women and honor.

Feudalism and chivalry should not be conflated. There's a good introduction to the subject on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalry.

Comment: I have no problem with the insanity aspect. But "which assails my reason" is operative here. In other words, he is suffering an assault or abuse to the system. _Perder la razón_ is literally "lose the reason". _Tener la razón_ is literally "to have the reason". _sin_ means "without". The first means "go crazy" and the second means "to be correct", but I cannot argue that that _sinrazón_ always means "incorrect". That is why I said that this is out of scope for this site. There are just too many nuances to the word _sinrazón_ in Spanish, and Cervantes was using several of them.

Comment: Tu sais que your French is showing quand tu dis *Don **Quichotte*** parce que a nuestro caballero los españoles le llaman *Don **Quijote*** mientras los mejicanos and the Americans we call him *Don Quixote*. :)

Comment: I can't spell in four languages. :) I just write off the top of my head and forget to proofread but I have no accent in four languages, can you top that??

Comment: Cascabel, tener razón is to be right, literally, to have reason. But it is clear that here sinrazón means crazy, mad. No tienes razón: you are not right, you are not correct [in something you say].

Comment: It would seem that all this has been pointless: [_En cuanto a una posible traducción, teniendo en cuenta que la frase es difícil de entender y posiblemente ambigua a propósito, yo favorecería unreason, para mantener esa aliteración de razón-sinrazón-razón-razón-razón que creo que era la intención original de Silva, y que no se mantendría con madness u otras posibilidades. El significado poco importa, si hacemos caso a Cervantes, y me da que Silva no le dio mucha importancia tampoco._](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/significado-de-sinraz%c3%b3n-en-don-quijote)